# Trying to migrate tables in code for .net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am setting up **IdentityServer4** with **Aspnet.Identity**.
I followed a tutorial which shows how to create the database and seed in code. I have a method that looks like this:

```
public static void SeedIdentityServerDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var persistedGrantDbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
        var configurationDbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();

        persistedGrantDbContext.Database.Migrate();
        configurationDbContext.Database.Migrate();

        CreateIdentityResources(configurationDbContext);
        CreateApiResources(configurationDbContext);
        CreateClients(configurationDbContext);
    }
}
```

This works with no issues and creates my database plus the tables / data needed for **IdentityServer4**.

I am now [reading the **IdentityServer** documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/8_aspnet_identity.html) for implementing with **AspNet.Identity** but it shows **MVC** rather than **Api** and I want to continue doing it the way I have been.

So I updated my **DbContext** to this

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    // ReSharper disable once SuggestBaseTypeForParameter
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And my **User** class to this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
}
```

My startup now has this:

```
services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

var buildServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var config = buildServiceProvider.GetService<IOptions<Config>>();

services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.Value.ConnectionString));
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And I tried to update my seed method to this:

```
public static void SeedIdentityServerDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var persistedGrantDbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
        var configurationDbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        var databaseContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();

        persistedGrantDbContext.Database.Migrate();
        configurationDbContext.Database.Migrate();
        databaseContext.Database.Migrate();

        CreateIdentityResources(configurationDbContext);
        CreateApiResources(configurationDbContext);
        CreateClients(configurationDbContext);
        CreateUsers(serviceProvider);
    }
}

private static void CreateUsers(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    const string email = "test.test@test.com";
    var userManager = provider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    var administrator = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email).Result;

    if (administrator != null) return;

    administrator = new User {UserName = email, Email = email, EmailConfirmed = true};
    var result = userManager.CreateAsync(administrator, "password").Result;

    if (!result.Succeeded)
        throw new Exception(result.Errors.First().Description);

    result = userManager.AddClaimsAsync(administrator, new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Test Test"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Test"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Test"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, email),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
    }).Result;

    if (!result.Succeeded)
        throw new Exception(result.Errors.First().Description);
}
```

When it gets to the `CreateUsers` method, it fails stating:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.

Here are the tables it does create:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have not migrated your `IdentityContext` so all the tables related to it are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not happy with the solution....But what I have done is just follow the normal way of doing things. So first of all, mapping any AspNetIdentity tables as I see fit:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(m => m.ToTable("Users"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(m => m.ToTable("Roles"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("RoleClaims"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserClaims"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserLogins"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserRoles"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserTokens"));
}
```

And then calling `add-migration`:

```
add-migration Init -Context DatabaseContext
```

followed by `update-database`

```
update-database -Context DatabaseContext
```

Because the [commands in the documentation set up 2 DbContexts](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/7_entity_framework.html#database-schema-changes-and-using-ef-migrations), I now have mutliple which is why I have to speficy the context in both `add-migration` and `update-database`.

Once I ran these two commands, I then changed my seed method to this:

```
public static void SeedIdentityServerDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var persistedGrantDbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
        var configurationDbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();

        persistedGrantDbContext.Database.Migrate();
        configurationDbContext.Database.Migrate();

        CreateIdentityResources(configurationDbContext);
        CreateApiResources(configurationDbContext);
        CreateClients(configurationDbContext);
        CreateUsers(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have removed the `databaseContext.Database.Migrate();` call as it isn't needed anymore.

The `CreateUsers` method now runs and seeds properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the code for your `CreateUsers` method, but by default many of the `UserManager`/`SignInManager` methods seem to look for the `AspNetUsers` table by default (unless you specify a different table name). To keep using the default, you can add this to the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DatabaseContext` class:

```
builder.Entity<User>(b => b.ToTable("AspNetUsers"));
```

Otherwise, your `Migrate` command will probably create a "Users" table which `UserManager`/`SignInManager` wouldn't know about. If you want the table to be called "Users" that's fine, just change the above to:

```
builder.Entity<User>(b => b.ToTable("Users"));
```

That way, `UserManager`/`SignInManager` will know which table to use for the `User` entity.

Reference: [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model#change-tablecolumn-names-and-facets)

Comment: I have added the code for the `CreateUsers` Method. As for the tables, it doesn't create **Users** or **AspNetusers**. I have attached a screenshot of what it does create

Comment: @r3plica Your screenshot doesn't include any Identity tables at all - it only includes the PersistedGrantDbContext and ConfigurationDbContext tables. You can see an example of combining them all in one context here if you're interested: https://github.com/crgolden/crgolden.Oidc/blob/master/Data/OidcDbContext.cs

Comment: Hey, that is what I said in my comment to you :) I will have a crack at this combined DbContext and see if it's any better